# Integrating a set of second order differential equations with Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, ode, numerical-integration

I have a set of second order differential equations:

[image]

and I would like to solve for [image] using `odeint` in python. Is this possible?

I have attempted to do it, but my code does not give me the expected result.

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, matplotlib.font_manager as fm,os
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D

initial_state = [0.1, 0, 0]
a = 4
time_points = np.linspace(0, 100, 10000)

def my_system(current_state, t):
    theta1, theta2, theta3 = current_state

    d2theta1_dt2 = -a*(2*theta1-theta2-theta3)
    d2theta2_dt2 = -a*(2*theta2-theta1-theta3)
    d2theta3_dt2 = -a*(2*theta3-theta1-theta2)

    return [d2theta1_dt2, d2theta2_dt2, d2theta3_dt2]

xyz = odeint(my_system, initial_state, time_points)

theta1 = xyz[:, 0]
theta2 = xyz[:, 1]
theta3 = xyz[:, 2]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.xaxis.set_pane_color((1,1,1,1))
ax.yaxis.set_pane_color((1,1,1,1))
ax.zaxis.set_pane_color((1,1,1,1))
ax.plot(theta1, theta2, theta3, color='g', alpha=0.7, linewidth=0.6)
ax.set_title('plot', fontproperties=title_font)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `odeint` expects a 1st order system. Rewrite the system as a system of 6 first order equations. [Youtube example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3iu1qiJue4)

Comment: The SciPy Cookbook has [an example of rewriting two coupled second order equations as a system of four first order equations](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/CoupledSpringMassSystem.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the fix to insert the first order derivatives is rather quick,

```
def my_system(current_state, t):
    theta1, theta2, theta3, omega1, omega2, omega3 = current_state

    d2theta1_dt2 = -a*(2*theta1-theta2-theta3)
    d2theta2_dt2 = -a*(2*theta2-theta1-theta3)
    d2theta3_dt2 = -a*(2*theta3-theta1-theta2)

    return [ omega1, omega2, omega3, d2theta1_dt2, d2theta2_dt2, d2theta3_dt2]
```

where the first three entries of the state are again the angles, and the second three are their velocities.

---

You will also need to add initial values for the angular velocities to the initial state vector.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that `initial_state = [0.1, 0, 0]` must also be fixed.